# VB.NET Reference new form object's listview from another class

Tags: database, vb.net, forms, listview, sqldatareader

On a form i have a listview with a contextmenu.

Right click on a listview item shows the context menu.

When i click on the menubutton, what i would like to happen is the following :

A form i called TaskLog will appear, it contains only a listview
(This is the code i have) :

```
Private Sub ShowLogToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ShowLogToolStripMenuItem.Click
    logform = New TaskLog()
    logform.task = "taskname"
    logform.server = "servername"
    logform.Show()
End Sub
```

That listview should be filled with data from a database before it shows, therefore i have the following in the load event of the TaskLog Form

```
Public Class TaskLog
 Private db As Database = New Database
 Public task As String
 Public server As String

Private Sub TaskLog_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    db.connect()
    db.getTaskLog(task, server, Me)
End Sub
End Class
```

Then in the database class gettask function i call the database, store data in an object, which all works fine. Only problem here is that my database object cannot find the listview and the form, even if i pass the form as a variable to this function (frm as TaskLog).

```
    Public Function getTaskLog(taskname As String, server As String, frm As TaskLog) As Boolean

    'Declare sql command variable
    Dim command As New SqlCommand

    'Try to open db connection
    Try
        connection.Open()
        command.Connection = connection

        'Set query to command object text
        command.CommandText = "select * from tasklog where ltrim(rtrim(server)) Like'" & Trim(server) & "%' and ltrim(rtrim(task)) = '" & Trim(taskname) & "'"
        'Declare data reading pbject
        Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

        'Perform operations while rows are returned from database

        While rdr.Read()

            'Store database entry to TaskData Object 
            taskLogData = New TaskData(rdr("frequency").ToString, rdr("start"), rdr("duration"), rdr("delay"), rdr("rescheduled"), rdr("forced"), rdr("task"), rdr("server"), rdr("email"), rdr("message"), rdr("status"), rdr("logtime"))

            Dim new_item As New  _
            ListViewItem(Trim(taskLogData.task_server.ToString))
            new_item.SubItems.Add(Trim(taskLogData.task_name.ToString))
            new_item.SubItems.Add(Trim(taskLogData.task_status.ToString))
            new_item.SubItems.Add(Trim(taskLogData.task_frequency.ToString))
            new_item.SubItems.Add(Trim(taskLogData.task_nextrun.ToString))
            new_item.SubItems.Add(Trim(taskLogData.task_forced.ToString))
            new_item.SubItems.Add(Trim(taskLogData.task_rescheduled.ToString))
            new_item.SubItems.Add(Trim(taskLogData.task_rescheduled.ToString))

            new_item.Group = frm.ListView1.Groups(Trim(taskData.task_status.ToString))

            frm.ListView1.Items.Add(new_item)

        End While

        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception 'If connection fails return error message
        MessageBox.Show("Error while retrieving records on table..." & ex.Message, "Load Records")
        Return True

    Finally 'After connection close database 
        connection.Close()
    End Try

End Function
```

Object Reference not set to an instance of an object appears on the following line in the function above:

```
    frm.ListView1.Items.Add(new_item)
```

Can someone see the problem, and hopefully some help ? I tried a couple of things but still not sure about what to do best here. Thanks !!!!!!!

Comment: Have you tried to comment out the line that tries to assign a Group to the new ListViewItem?

Comment: That worked... Of course, stupid me, i do not need those groups in this one.. THANKS ! how can i upvote your answer ?

Comment: I provide an answer below, you could accept it and/or upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
 new_item.Group = frm.ListView1.Groups(Trim(taskData.task_status.ToString))
```

refers to a Group that should exist in the ListView1. You could comment it out if it is not needed

Comment: Thanks , haha did you cheat the website ?

Comment: Ah yes now I understand, no I have simply upvoted your question because is clear and well exposed. The question is a bit long to read but it is easy to follow your reasoning. As a consequence you reached the [15 reputation mark that allows upvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges). See you again in SO :-)

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried my best to make it as readable as I can. see you next time ;)